# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 SecretKeyFactory not available error

Tags: java, hash, passwords, sha512, pbkdf2

I am trying to use the **Security API** in **Java EE 8**, hashing the password. I created a **@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition**

```
@BasicAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
    realmName = "Book Realm"
)
@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition(
    dataSourceLookup = "jdbc/userAuth",
    callerQuery = "select password from users where USERNAME = ?",
    groupsQuery = "select g.GROUP_NAME from USER_GROUPS ug, users u, GROUPS g where ug.USER_ID = u.user_id and g.GROUP_ID= ug.GROUP_ID and u.USERNAME=?"
    hashAlgorithm = Pbkdf2PasswordHash.class,
    hashAlgorithmParameters = {
            "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Iterations=3072",
            "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Algorithm=PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512",
            "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.SaltSizeBytes=64"
    }
)
@DeclareRoles({"user", "admin"})
@WebServlet("/securedServlet")
@ServletSecurity(
    @HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"admin"}))
public class SecuredServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().write("Congratulations, login successful.");
    }
}
```

when I deploy the war file to the Glassfish 5 application server I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 SecretKeyFactory not available
```

This exception comes from the class that I have created to automaticly create and insert the user in to the database.

The relevant parts of this class:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/userAuth")
private DataSource dataSource;

@Inject
private Pbkdf2PasswordHash passwordHash;

public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object init) {
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Iterations", "3072");
        parameters.put("Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Algorithm", "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        parameters.put("Pbkdf2PasswordHash.SaltSizeBytes", "64");
        passwordHash.initialize(parameters);
        executeUpdate(dataSource, "INSERT INTO USERS (USER_ID,USERNAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,PASSWORD) VALUES (1,'beaver','Beaver','The Dam','Lake','" + passwordHash.generate("beaverattack".toCharArray()) + "')");
```

In the pom.xml I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
  <version>8.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.security.enterprise</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have you installed the JCE (JavaCryptoExtention)? I think it is part of that. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: I think I have not installed the JCE (JavaCryptoExtension). I was not aware of this. I try to install it now.

Comment: I had those file already within the folder: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\security\policy\unlimited

Also I tried to modify the java.security file (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\security) 

Setting the crypto.policy property to unlimited (it was commented out by default)

Comment: Replace the existing files

Comment: I have replaced the files (local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar). After that I restarted the JVM (also tried with rebooting the OS) I am still getting the same exception as before.

Comment: I found out what caused the problem. Somehow the JDK 11 was installed along with the Glassfish 5. When I realized this, I changed the JDK version same to jdk1.8.0_211. It is now properly generating the hashed password, altough I still can not login with the created user. Here is the generated password for 'beaverattack': 
 

 PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512:3072:CdWkC7KJjvk4inU58qrhSWkERVbLrPhLMjg63jxVDf3Nn+weIRvWYWWZDxstVVHSdDkxAUnwcRgCyp9FFwqKcA==:KGmOJA0iWksZVtiKWiSUpddMfGUH6EDB2skDYWT78W8=